# How to get user's current location from network provider in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

In offline mode how to get user's current location in ios, is it possible to get the location by network provider?

Comment: You can use Core Location, and the device will use whatever sources are available, including from the network provider.

Comment: For Objective C 
https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

Comment: Check my answer brother.It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I give you full solution.If you want to achieve this you should use **core location framework**.

**First step:**

> import CoreLocation framework in .h file

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

**Second Step:** You need to add following things in your plist file

> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription  string  Whatever you want to write write here
>
> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  string  Whatever you want to write write here
>
> privacy - location usage description string  Whatever you want to write write here

Kindly see the screen shot below

[image]

**Third step:**

> Add CLLocationManagerDelegate

**Fourth step:**

> Create an instance of the CLLocationManager class and store a strong reference

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**Why do we store CLLocationManager property as strong reference here?**

> Keeping a strong reference to the location manager object is required until all tasks involving that object are complete. 
>    Because most location manager tasks run asynchronously, storing your location manager in a local variable is insufficient.

Now ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

}
@property (nonatomic , strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
- (IBAction)actionGetCurrentLocation:(id)sender;
@end
```

Following steps to be implemented in ViewController.m

**Fifth step:**

> Before starting to update the location we should ask permission and instantiate the CLLocationManager.Then we should start updating the location

```
- (IBAction)actionGetCurrentLocation:(id)sender
{
   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO){
      NSLog(@"Your location service is not enabled, So go to Settings>Location Services");
    }
   else{
      NSLog(@"Your location service is enabled");
   }
   if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
   {
      [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
   }
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**Sixth step:**

> Add CLLocationManager Delegate methods

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize locationManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);   //@"Error" //@"Failed to Get Your Location"  //@"OK"
   UIAlertController *errorAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
   UIAlertAction *actionOK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
   [self presentViewController:errorAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
   [errorAlert addAction:actionOK];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
     }
  }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateLocation are : %@", locations);
    currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    if (currentLocation != nil) 
    {
       NSLog(@"The latitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
       NSLog(@"The longitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
     }
}

#pragma mark - UIButton Action
 - (IBAction)actionGetCurrentLocation:(id)sender
{
   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO){
      NSLog(@"Your location service is not enabled, So go to Settings>Location Services");
    }
   else{
      NSLog(@"Your location service is enabled");
   }
   if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
   {
      [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
   }
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```