# CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't fire confirm alert for WatchOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, cllocationmanager, watchos-2

I want to simulate location in watchOS simulator.
But the location manager doesn't fire confirmation alert about using location inside the application.

CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't fire confirm alert for WatchOS
That is ,

`[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`
 do nothing.
in `info.plist` file there is `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` which is `The app needs your location`.

Why this feature doesn't work? May be I miss something?

Comment: you already run `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`

Comment: yes, i did it. i'm catching the error iinside `didFailWithError`

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991985/how-to-get-users-current-location-from-network-provider-in-objective-c/38995060#38995060

Comment: @user3182143 , I'm using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021583/location-detection-in-watchos-simulator-has-been-failed

Comment: @user3182143 , I did the same steps for base application which works correctly. the problem is about watchOS. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vyacheslav, did you ever resolve this? I am facing the same issue on watchOS, hoping you have got a resolution, thanks!