# CLLocation current location not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-location

I have this code in my class `ViewController`:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}


- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Did finish with error - %@", error);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to get your location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"did Update Location - %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if(currentLocation != nil) {
        _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the location or the popup for allowing access.

I am using the Core Location framework.

On button click I am printing latitude, longitude and address in labels.

I am testing this on the simulator.

Comment: I remind you that add the authorization request in plist and  check with your device you can get.

Comment: Have you add the authorization request explanation in your .plist ?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991985/how-to-get-users-current-location-from-network-provider-in-objective-c/38995060#38995060

Comment: KAR check above link it gives you the solution

Comment: I added in info plist file. thanks @user3182143

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location Services not working in iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Simulator wont work with location enabled services use `Apple Device` for perfect testing.

Add the following keys inside your `info.plist` file to get allow access popup.

[image]

or add them as updating `info.plist` file source code.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>message for location uses</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>message for location uses</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in viewDidLoad...

```
//---- For getting current gps location
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])  {

        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    //------
```

You also have to add a string for the **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** or **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** keys to the app's Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    locationManager.delegate=self;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

you can add in your plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>


<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
```